# How do I add a black border to every image in a folder and output the result into another folder?

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew, imagemagick.net

I have a folder with 500 images, I want to add a 5% black border to all of them and then output into a new folder just to keep the originals intact but can't find online support for Mac.

The Input folder is: /Users/Luca/Desktop/Stampa/Italiane/*

The Output folder I want it to be is: /Users/Luca/Desktop/Mogrify

I've found something online but mostly for Windows and couldn't reproduce it on my Mac for some reason, I've tried various things without any results.

So I've tried tinkering with it and done:

`mogrify -border 5%x5% -bordercolor Black /Users/Luca/Desktop/Stampa/Italiane/* -path /Users/Luca/Desktop/Mogrify`

But it outputs nothing, just work on the images for a while, create a white border card and then deletes it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I wasn't using my brain, if someone else wants to do what I've asked just duplicate your folder and let Imagemagick work on the first one, so if it outputs a bad result you have it already saved. The code I used is:

```
mogrify -bordercolor Black -border 5%x5% /Users/Luca/Desktop/Stampa/Italiane/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer is to use the `-path` operator which is provided for that very purpose, i.e. to write the output images in a different folder:

```
mkdir OUTPUT
magick -path OUTPUT -crop ... -border ... *.png
```

---

In the same vein, you can also set a new format (e.g. PNG) for the output files with:

```
magick -format PNG -crop ... -border ... *.jpg
```